# Entity Framework 6 t4 template EdmMetadataLoader error

Tags: entity-framework, t4

I have a TestModel.edmx file and in the design view I right clicked and selected "Add code generation item." The TestModel.Context.tt and TestModel.tt files that are generated both have the following line in them:

```
var loader = new EdmMetadataLoader(textTransform.Host, textTransform.Errors);
```

When I try to build the project, it fails because "Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'EdmMetadataLoader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Why are there errors in the .tt files that are generated by default? Doing an internet search of EdmMetadataLoader comes up with basically nothing, so I don't even know what namespace is missing. Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks!

**Edit:** I opened the EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude file on my computer and the EdmMetadataLoader class is commented out. Is that intentional, or do I have an incorrect EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude file?

Answer (score 0):

I manually deleted the EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude file in \Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes and then re-installed "Entity Framework Tools for Visual Studio 2012" and the new EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude file had the EdmMetadataLoader class uncommented. Not sure why this happened at all but oh well.